# css change checked radio button background

Tags: css

I use the following custom-radio want to change checked button background to blue

```css
.custom-radio label {
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.custom-radio label>input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-button-group ">
  <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group custom-radio">
    <label class="btn border ">
            <input type="radio"  name="direction" id="direction-0" checked value="left">
            <span>left</span>
        </label>
    <label class="btn border">
            <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction-1"  value="top">
            <span>right</span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

when custom-radio checked background color changed
active custom-radio want to change checked background to blue

Answer (score 0):

You would need to move your styles to the span rather than have them on the label then you can use `input[type="radio"]:checked + span` to change the background colour

```css
.custom-radio span {
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"]:checked+span {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-button-group ">
  <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group custom-radio">
    <label class="btn border ">
        <input type="radio"  name="direction" id="direction-0" checked value="left">
        <span>left</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn border">
        <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction-1"  value="top">
        <span>right</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```